# How to avoid two request in component?

Tags: angular

I have a component that loads data and renders it:

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.getPage();

        this.eventsService.subjectFilterDistributionReset.subscribe((value) => {
            if (value) {
                this.paginationService.reset();
                this.loadPage();
            }
        });

        this.eventsService.subjectFilterDistribution.pipe(filter((filterUrl) => filterUrl)).subscribe((filterUrl) => {
            const page = 1;
            this.paginationService.setFilterBy(filterUrl);
            this.paginationService.setCurrentPage(page);
            this.paginationService.calculateOffsetLimit(page);
            this.loadPage();
        });

        this.eventsService.subjectSortingDistribution.pipe(filter(Boolean)).subscribe((sortedList: ListItem[]) => {
            this.paginationService.setSortBy(getSortingString(sortedList));
            this.loadPage();
        });
    }
```

As you can see by default it calls `this.getPage();`:

```
public getPage(page: number = 1): void {
    this.loadDataRequest();
}
```

Also it has listener:

```
 this.eventsService.subjectFilterDistribution.pipe(filter((filterUrl) => filterUrl)).subscribe((filterUrl) => {})
```

Problem is when I route to this component and send message `this.eventsService.subjectFilterDistribution`.

It calls  `this.getPage();`, because it is in ngOnIinit.

So, how to split up loading by default and by events?

Problem is that I need to call method `this.loadPage();` only one time.

1. When component is loaded
2. When event subject comes

Comment: Sorry mate i don't understand where the problem is, can you describe it better? also add the code in loadDataRequest.

Comment: Problem is when component is loaded it calls `this.loadPage();` and if there is any event it also calls `this.loadPage();`. So, method `this.loadPage();` should be called only one time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the combineLatest method moving the logic you have in each individual subscription in the tap operator because tecnically those are side effects.

```js
public filterDistributionReset =  
     this.eventsService.subjectFilterDistributionReset.pipe(
               filter(res => !!res),
               tap(_ => this.paginationService.reset()));

// Add also the other subjects


public combinedSubjects = combineLatest(
  filterDistributionReset,
  filterDistribution,
  sortingDistribution);


ngOnInit() {
 this.combinedSubjects.subscribe(_ => this.loadPage())
}
```